# Person that owns at least 10 dogs?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables:

```
 person( sin, name, address)
 owner(dogowner_id, dog_id, is_primary_owner_of_dog)
 dog( dog_no, breed_id )
 dog_breed( breed_id, breed )
```

How would you go about finding all people who are the main( primary owner) of at least 10 Yellow Labs? I'm super confused about this and help would me much appreciated.

**Edit:** NO nested queries and aggregation please!

Comment: You can't do this with out at least a count(*) aggregation. Why the aversion?

Comment: @Matt: it's probably homework.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be leveraging an `IN` on the `person` table:

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE sin IN (
    SELECT dogowner_id FROM owner o
        JOIN dog d ON o.dog_id = d.dog_no
        JOIN dog_breed b ON b.breed_id = d.breed_id
    WHERE is_primary_owner_of_dog AND
        b.breed = 'Yellow Lab'
    GROUP BY dogowner_id
    HAVING COUNT(dogowner_id) >= 10
)
```

The inner query will determine what "primary owners" own *at least* 10 dogs and the outer query will then return those respective `person` records.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), dogowner
from owner 
  inner join dog on dog.dog_no = owner.dog_id
  inner join dob_breed on dog.breed_id = dog_breed.breed_id
where dog_breed.breed = 'Yellow Lab'
group by dogowner
having count(*) >=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with `join` and `group by`:

```
select dogowner, count(*) as numyellowlabs
from owner o
     dog d
     on o.dog_id = d.dog_no join
     dog_breed db 
     on d.breed_id = db.breed_id
where breed = 'Yellow Lab'
group by dogowner
having count(*) >=10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) AS numberOfDogs, dogowner AS dogOwner
FROM owner AS o
  INNER JOIN dog AS d
     ON d.dog_no = o.dog_id
  INNER JOIN dob_breed as b
     ON d.breed_id = b.breed_id
WHERE b.breed = 'Yellow Lab'
   AND o.is_primary_owner_of_dog = "True"
GROUP BY dogowner
HAVING count(*) >=10
```

The other queries were very close...the part that was missing was "main( primary owner) of at least 10 Yellow Labs? "   I don't know what the values of is_primary_owner_of_dog are... true/false, 0/1, yes/no.... so the query will need to be modified accordingly. But otherwise this should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Taking into consideration that there shall be no nested queries and aggregation, you can use the analytic function COUNT() and joins to accomplish the task, as below:

```
Select P.*
From Person P Inner Join (Select DISTINCT Dogowner_Id, Count(O.Dog_Id) Over (Partition By O.Dogowner_Id) Dog_Count
From Owner O Inner Join Dog D On O.Dog_Id = D.Dog_No 
Inner Join Dog_Breed Db On D.Breed_Id = Db.Breed_Id
Where   Db.Breed = 'Yellow Lab'
And     O.Is_Primary_Owner_Of_Dog = 1) Counts
On      Counts.Dogowner_Id = P.Sin
Where   Counts.Dog_Count >= 10
```